# How to serialize non-serializable base class in standard serialization?

Tags: java, serialization

I can't control the source code of the base class, then, how can I use standard serialization on the subclass?

In this example, field `a` is not serialized at all, though B is serializable:

// a.jar

```
class A {
    int a;
}
```

// b.jar

```
class B
        extends A
        implements Serializable {
    int b;
}

public class HelloWorldApp {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception {
        B b = new B();
        b.a = 10;
        b.b = 20;

        ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(buf);
        out.writeObject(b);
        out.close();

        byte[] bytes = buf.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream _in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(_in);
        B x = (B) in.readObject();
        System.out.println(x.a);
        System.out.println(x.b);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
0
20
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't!
field `a` will not be serialized!
Work around: implement your custom serialization. You should implement `Externalizable` interface and `writeExternal, readExternal` methods.
In thess methods you can write and read value of your `a` field.

Comment: Then, is it a need to mark Serializble interface on all non-empty-constructor-only classes?

Comment: No, not necessary. You will have next code: public class B extends A implements Externalizable { public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) { out.write(a); out.write(b); } public void readExternals(ObjectInput in) { a = in.readInt(); b = in.readInt(); } }

Comment: -1. Make up your mind. Either you can or you can't. Not both at the same time.

Comment: +1. Correct and useful answer. @EJP: he's saying Xie can't use standard serialization, but can workaround it with custom serialization. I don't see any ambiguity.

Comment: @helios He didn't say that at all. He said, and I quote, "you can't". He then proceeded to contradict himself. He is also incorrect to say that you need to implement Externalizable. You could do it with custom `writeObject()` and `readObject()` methods. Either way the client would still think he is using 'standard serialization'.

Comment: @EJP: ok, it's a matter of what standard serialization means. I agree with you that it remains standard serialization even after implementintg Externalizable or read/writeObject. In case of read/writeObject: what happens with superclass? I understand that read/writeObject only overrides the way the current class is written, not superclass. That's what Externalizable is for: taking complete control over current class and superclasses serialization.

Comment: @helios If you write your own `writeObject()` method you can call `defaultWriteObject()` and also serialize anything else you like, including fields of the superclass if you can access them. Similarly your `readObject()` method can call `defaultReadObject()` and also deserialize any extra stuff you serialized in your `writeObject()` method. This is all documented.

Comment: @EJP implementation of Externalizable does not change client side serialization: you use object input/output streams to read/write object. From this point of view it is standard way. But mechanizm of class serialisation is not standard. Only class identifier will be serialized. You should take care about fields. So it is custom. Not standard from this point of view. What you want to prove?

Comment: @EJP: anyway I thought that overriding read/writeObject should be called for each class in the hierarchy, so implementing those methods in a child Serializable class doesn't resolve the lack of serialization on a parent class.

Comment: @alexey28 What I am 'trying to prove' is what I have already stated. The OP doesn't not have to implement Externalizable to achieve this objective.

Comment: @Helios You are mistaken. See my comment again.

Comment: "The writeObject method is responsible for writing the state of the object for its particular class"... and ... "The method does not need to concern itself with the state belonging to its superclasses or subclasses". So I understand that the JVM calls writeObject on each class. If you implement writeObject for B it will be ok, but when the JVM is going to serialize the par for A class, as a is not serializable... it will fail. That's my concern about using write/readObject.

Comment: @helios It won't 'fail'. It won't serialize the non-Serializable base class, that's all. As I have already said above, if you can access the base class members from the Serializable class, you can serialize them yourself in the Serializable class's writeObject() method, and deserialize them in its readObject() method. This is fact. You don't seem to be grasping the concept.

Comment: @EJP: yes, not necessary implements Externalizable. But you can atchive it with Externalizable. This is the way you can solve the problem.